# Javascript - how to call function correctly

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I don't really understand how to call a Javascript function properly on document ready. My goal is to resize a div depending on the height of browser window, and I took this code from another answer on SO. What am I doing wrong?

```
function resizeElementHeight(element) {
  var height = 0;
  var body = window.document.body;
  if (window.innerHeight) {
      height = window.innerHeight;
  } else if (body.parentElement.clientHeight) {
      height = body.parentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if (body && body.clientHeight) {
      height = body.clientHeight;
  }
  element.style.height = ((height - element.offsetTop) + "px");
}

$(document).ready(resizeElementHeight($('#global_image')));
```

The element I am trying to call has the id "global_image", but I get "cannot set property height of undefined", and I feel lost in how to providing the right element to the function. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function resizeElementHeight expects a DOM-element, not a JavaScript object. To expand on techfoobar's answer you should change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    resizeElementHeight($('#global_image')[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`ready()` expects a *function* as its argument. Right now, you are calling `resizeElementHeight()` and passing its *return value* to `ready()`.

In your current code, at the point of calling `resizeElementHeight()` the DOM is not yet ready and the element `#global_image` is not yet in the DOM tree.

You should change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    resizeElementHeight($('#global_image'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the DOM object is not completely loaded when you call resizeElementHeight.replace by is:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    resizeElementHeight($('#global_image')[0]);
});
```